# Jquery keydown wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a press enter to send data using jquery but my code is not working. Anyone can tell me what i am missing here ?

```
<textarea name="reply" class="reply" id="replyChat" placeholder="Write your message"></textarea>
```

**JS**

```
function SendMessage() { 
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/reply",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $('.messages-body').append(html);
        }
      });
     }

   $('#replyChat').bind('keydown', function(e) {
      if(e.keyCode==13) {
        SendMessage();
    }
  });
  $('body').on("click",".reply-btn",function() {
     SendMessage();
 });
```

Click function is working fine just keydown doesn't work here.

Comment: it's working for me, is the element is dynamically generated

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle

Comment: is this code inside your document ready function?

Comment: @dr_debug yes it is in document ready.

Comment: @DevStud : is the element(textarea) is dynamically generated?

Comment: works for me :/

Comment: which jquery version you are using and once check console if getting any error

Comment: @rahul_m I have checked everything i am not getting any error from console.

Comment: which jquery version you are using

Comment: @PranavCBalan this is so nice question. That textarea is dynamically generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for the dynamically generated element, although use [`event.which`](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/) property which is suggested by jQuery.

```js
function SendMessage() {
  console.log('hi');
  // replace with your ajax code
}

$('body').on('keydown', '#replyChat', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    SendMessage();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="reply" class="reply" id="replyChat" placeholder="Write your message"></textarea>
```